# IIS Reverse proxy configuration

Tags: iis, dns, reverse-proxy, web-hosting, windows-server-2012

I have two sites in my IIS 8 server. Site MyProjectA and MyProjectB, for each project I have a domain name, lets say myprojecta.com and myprojectb.com. I have set in my DNS provider that both domains points to the server IP. I have configured so MyProjectA runs on 443 and MyprojectB runs on 8181, both SSL.

So if I browse to:

- https://myprojecta.com I see MyProjectA and its working fine

If I browse to:

- https://myprojectb.com:8181 I see MyProjectB and that is working
  fine.

But now I wonder, how can I configure so I can omit the :8181 part, and in turn reach MyProjectB site by browsing to https://myprojectb.com only (and with correct certificate). As far as I understood this should be possible with a reverse proxy configuration in IIS but I cannot get it to work. Anyone can help how to achieve that?

Comment: Use SNI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability Reverse proxy is not even needed.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! @LexLi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using IIS 8, the simplest approach is to set up multiple HTTPS sites at port 443 using SNI support. Then there is no need of reverse proxy.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability)